How to structure many-to-one relationship without a new table
I have a scenario where users enter their favorite fruit, and they can choose more than one option. This isn't a central feature of my database, so I am hesitant to create a new table to model this many-to-one relationship. As an alternative, I was thinking of storing this data in a concatenated string so it could be stored with the rest of the user data. The drawback of this option seems to be that it would be slightly more challenging to parse the string every time we wanted to do analysis using the favorite_fruit column.
Does anyone have any thoughts?



The relationship table is the only proper way to do it. This is a many-to-many relationship, because a user can like multiple fruits, and multiple users can like the same fruit.

Yep, don't muddle through. This is an m:n relation and asks for a bridge table, aka association table.

Without a new table you are missing all of the benefits of normalized data:
Better database organization,Reduces redundancy,More consistent data,Improves security,Reduces cost,Data becomes easier to work with.
